# How to call a "wizard view" with {% url %} statement in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-formwizard

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^signin_client$', views.signin_client, name='signin_client') # normal view,
url(r'^signup_owner$', SignupOwnerWizard.as_view()), # wizard view
```

In a 'normal view' case: `<a href='{% url "myapp.views.signin_client" %}'>` works.

But I can't figure how to do the same thing for my "wizard view". Of course, I don't want to hardcode the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add name to the pattern:

```
url(r'^signup_owner$', SignupOwnerWizard.as_view(), name='signup_owner'),
```

And than use the name in `{% url %}` tag:

```
<a href='{% url "signup_owner" %}'>
```

If you use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) you would need a namespace prefix:

```
<a href='{% url "mynamespace:signup_owner" %}'>
```

Comment: It was easy :) Thanks a lot. (I'll mark it solved as soon as possible)